# Why is my Octave GUI editor so buggy? How can I fix it?

Tags: editor, octave

The editor for the GUI is a complete mess. When I create a brand new script, the spacing and font are relatively ok.
However, if I open any existing function, it is shown with way too much space between lines, and spaces and tabs show way more space than they should. An example is shown below:

[image]

I tried selecting the Edit - Preferences - General - Use custom file editor options, and chose "notepad++ -n%l %f. I have notepad++ installed already on my computer.
When I selected this option and clicked ok, the Octave GUI crashed. When I tried to reopen a file now, I get the error "could not start custom file editor".

If I change the font, it temporarily fixes the issue. But none of the changes persist. Often clicking OK crashes octave. And any time it's reopened, the fonts revert to default, and the spacing problems returns.

How can I make the editor show an appropriate leading and space width?
I would also like to be able to further customize, if possible. For example I'd like it to use a dark theme. But for now just showing a reasonable space between lines would make this at least useable.

I'm using Windows 10, Octave version 6.4.0

Comment: This looks to me like an Octave bug, not something you're doing wrong and probably not something you can fix yourself. Come by one of the Octave support sites and report it as a bug to the Octave maintainers: Savannah Octave bug tracker (https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave) or Octave Discourse (https://octave.discourse.group/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll report it there